# How to make an object in a parent form accessible from a child form?

Tags: c#, forms, oop, object, inheritance

I am trying to make my player object from my parent form accessible from my child form but the instance in the parent form appears to be only private is there any way of making it public or protected?

The player is created from a class I made within the solution which contains the player's picture box image properties and methods for movement which are controlled by buttons within the parent form.

I am aiming to create a game which feature several levels and each child form inherits the same layout and logic as the parent form but with different factors i.e. the player's starting position.

Parent form:

```
    public partial class ParentForm : Form
    {
         Player  player = new  player();//create player object
     ...
```

Child form:

```
public partial class Demo : Game.ParentForm
    {

    public Demo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    private void Demo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       player.SetPosition(11, 11, "up");
       //sets the position of the player (picturebox) in this child form                                      
    }
```

I have the error message "ParentForm.player is inaccessible due to its protection level" I believe this is due to player object's protection level being private but there does not appear to be a way to to change this.

Comment: I don't remember WInForms by heart. Can't you just write 'public Player player'?

Comment: I tried this, got an error message: "Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'Player'  is less accessible than field ParentForm.player"

Comment: That's because your Player class is also not public. Make it public too.

Comment: Better to use a setter/getter method.

Comment: also tried:  "public Player player = new Player();" and got the same error as above

Comment: @RobinSanders
Please provide the code of the Player class itself. Most likely it's declared as 'class Player' and should be 'public class Player' instead.

Comment: @VladStryapko that's it! thanks! changed to 'public class Player'

Comment: @RobinSanders
Please note that in general it's better not to access class fields directly and have some sort of encapsulation but it's out of scope of your question.